# Is it true that $\int_0^1 \lfloor x^{-1} \rfloor^{-1} x^n dx = \frac{1}{n+1}(\zeta(2)+\zeta(3) + \dots + \zeta(n+2) ) - 1$?

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-zeta

This question is inspired by the formula $$\displaystyle\int_0^1{\left\lfloor{1\over x}\right\rfloor}^{-1}\!\!dx={1\over2^2}+{1\over3^2}+{1\over4^2}+\cdots = \zeta(2)-1,$$
see for instance [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619411/prove-that-displaystyle-int-01-left-lfloor1-over-x-right-rfloor-1-d).

It appears that for any integer $n\geq 0$, we have

$$\int_0^1 \lfloor x^{-1} \rfloor^{-1} x^n dx = \frac{1}{n+1}(\zeta(2)+\zeta(3) + \dots + \zeta(n+2) ) - 1.$$

I believe that Yiorgos' answer could be generalized to prove the above formula. Can anyone pull it off?

*Side question*: If $n$ is replaced by a complex number $s$, for which values of $s$ does the integral converge? (We interpret $x^s$ as $\exp(x\log s)$, where $\log s$ is the principal branch of the complex log.) If the above formula is true, then for any integer $n\geq 0$, have $$\int_0^1 \lfloor x^{-1} \rfloor^{-1} ((n+1)x^n-nx^{n-1}) dx = \zeta(n+2) - 1.$$
Is it true that for complex value of $s$ for which the integral converges, we have
$$\int_0^1 \lfloor x^{-1} \rfloor^{-1} ((s+1)x^s-sx^{s-1}) dx = \zeta(s+2)-1?$$

Comment: Why not adapt the proof given over there? This seems straightforward...

Comment: @Bruno Joyal:   Check out [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360323/how-to-solve-an-definite-integral-of-floor-valute-function).

Comment: Dear @Did: That is also what I suggest! But I don't want to keep all of the fun to myself. :)

Comment: A numerical check gives me different results. Mind rechecking you're hypothesis? Specifically, the LHS is always greater than $1$, while the RHS is smaller than $1$.

Comment: Dear @nbubis: Thank you, I made a transcription error. It should be fixed now!

Comment: @BrunoJoyal - Still looks wrong - did you mean $\ldots \zeta(n+2)-(n+1)$?

Comment: Dear @nbubis : You are right. Sorry about that, my paper is a mess!

Answer (score 4):

Letting $t=x^{-1}$ so $dx=-t^{-2}dt$ this integral can be rewritten as:

$$\begin{align}\int_{1}^\infty \lfloor t\rfloor^{-1} t^{-(n+2)}dt &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}k\int_{k}^{k+1}t^{-(n+2)}dt \\&= \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\left(k^{-(n+1)}-(k+1)^{-(n+1)}\right)
\end{align}$$
That's pretty much the exact same as the proof for $n=0$.

Now, 
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{k}(k+1)^{-(n+1)}&= \frac{1}{k(k+1)}(k+1)^{-n}\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)(k+1)^{-n} \\
&=\frac{1}{k}(k+1)^{-n}- (k+1)^{-(n+1)}\\
&=\dots\text{ induction applied here on }\frac1k(k+1)^{-n}\dots\\
&=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}-\cdots-\frac{1}{(k+1)^{n+1}}
\end{align}$$

So $$\frac{1}{k}\left(k^{-(n+1)}-(k+1)^{-(n+1)}\right) = \left(\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{(k+1)^j}\right) + \frac{1}{k^{n+2}}+\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac1k$$

This yields the result you want.

The side question (at least when $s\neq -1$) essentially asks about when:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\left(k^{-(s+1)}-(k+1)^{-(s+1)}\right)$$ converges.  When $s$ is real and $s>-1$, the terms are positive, and bounded above by the sequence $k^{-(s+1)}-(k+1)^{-(s+1)}$, which is a telescoping sequence, so it converges.

Comment: Excellent! The key is really that neat partial fraction decomposition. Any thoughts on the side question?

Comment: Not sure about the side question.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the side question.

Assume that $ \Re s >1$. Letting $t=x^{-1}$ so $dx=-t^{-2}dt$ the initial integral can be rewritten as:

$$\begin{align}\int_{1}^\infty \lfloor t\rfloor^{-1} t^{-(s+2)}dt &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}k\int_{k}^{k+1}t^{-(s+2)}dt \\&= \frac{1}{s+1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\left(k^{-(s+1)}-(k+1)^{-(s+1)}\right)\\&= \frac{1}{s+1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{s+2}}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)^{s+1}}\right)
\end{align}$$
Thus
$$
\int_0^1 \lfloor x^{-1} \rfloor^{-1} (s+1)\:x^s \:\mathrm dx = \zeta(s+2)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)^{s+1}}, \quad  \Re s >1 \tag1
$$ and we have
$$
\int_0^1 \lfloor x^{-1} \rfloor^{-1} s\:x^{s-1} \:\mathrm dx = \zeta(s+1)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)^{s}}, \quad  \Re s >2. \tag2
$$
Then we may substract $(2)$ from $(1)$, using
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)^{s}}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)^{s+1}}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)^{s}}\left(1-\frac{1}{(k+1)}\right)=\zeta(s+1)-1
$$
to get, by analytic continuation, 
$$\int_0^1 \lfloor x^{-1} \rfloor^{-1} ((s+1)x^s-sx^{s-1}) dx = \zeta(s+2)-1, \quad \Re s >0.$$